# Card Carousel Bot is not working

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I executed the card-carousel sample in the node js BotBuilder-Sample https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-CarouselCards but in the bot emulator the bot is not replying. In console window it is throwing a error.

> ERROR: ChatConnector: receive - invalid token. Requested by unexpected app ID.

I've also put the app id and passed it to the bot emulator:

```
// Create chat bot and listen to messages
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: "ecdd3610-37d3-462b-b133-04b206108e44",
    appPassword: "umefqAXLO824?=coWBK20+["
});
```

Do you have any clue on how to solve the issue?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem ? Are you using .Net SDK?

Comment: Given its code extract, it's Node.js

Comment: You don't need to add the app id and password to test the sample just run the sample the way it is these two attributes are not required.

Comment: @AnitaGeorge...i used node js BotBuilder sample

Comment: You can see the lines of code throwing the error at line 172 here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/src/bots/ChatConnector.ts. 

Are you sure the appId is the same as what was registered in Bot Framework? And I assume the appId and appPassword were added to the emulator at the top?

Also: not a great idea to post the appPassword on Stack Overflow, BTW. You should redact it.

Comment: @Bill...yes app I'd is same.. no card bot in botbuilder sample is replying in bot emulator...

Comment: @Leo, are you using the Bot Framework Emulator or the 'Test in Web Chat' feature found in your bot on Azure? I encountered this before and just tested again to be sure.
When I use 'Test in Web Chat' and I hard code the AppId and AppPassword credentials I get that same ChatConnector error you list.
You will want to use 'process.env.MicrosoftAppId' & 'process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword', respectively, to get your credentials and it should work just fine (barring any other issues).

Answer (score 0):

> the bot emulator the bot is not replying. In console window it is throwing a error.
>
> ERROR: ChatConnector: receive - invalid token. Requested by unexpected app ID.

Only I can reproduce your issue is when I set the different `appId` and `appPassword` pairs in nodejs script and bot emulator.

Please double check the `appId` and `appPassword` pairs are exactly the same your set in nodejs script and bot emulator.

[image]

Additionally, if you only need a test, you can empty the pairs both in script and emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I migrated the bot form https://dev.botframework.com/bots to azure bot service it is working fine.Thanks for everbody contribution to the problem.